# Add viewModel to a view programatically

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, viewmodel, android-databinding

I have a `RecycleView` with a `StaggeredGridLayoutManager`. I add the views programatically in `RecycleViewAdapter`. The problem is that the layout of views use data binding :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

  <data>

    <variable
      name="viewModel"
      type="com.myapp.myViewModel" />
  </data>

  <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="vertical">
....
```

How can I set the viewModel to the views when I add them to recycleView?

This is my RecycleViewAdapter:

```
 class RecycleViewAdapter(context: Context, private val layouts: List<Int>) :
        RecyclerView.Adapter<RecycleViewAdapter.ViewHolder>() {
      override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return layouts.size
      }

      private val mInflater: LayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)
      private var mClickListener: ItemClickListener? = null

      override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.recycleview_row, parent, false)

        return ViewHolder(view)
      }

      override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val layout = layouts[position]
        val view = mInflater.inflate(layout, null)
        holder.layout.addView(view)
      }


      inner class ViewHolder internal constructor(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView),
          View.OnClickListener {
        internal val layout: LinearLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.layout)

        init {
          itemView.setOnClickListener(this)
        }

        override fun onClick(view: View) {
          if (mClickListener != null) mClickListener!!.onItemClick(view, adapterPosition)
        }
      }

      internal fun getItem(id: Int): Int {
        return layouts[id]
      }

      internal fun setClickListener(itemClickListener: ItemClickListener) {
        this.mClickListener = itemClickListener
      }

      interface ItemClickListener {
        fun onItemClick(view: View, position: Int)
      }
    }
```

My recycleview_row is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <data>

    <variable
      name="viewModel"
      type="com.myApp.BaseViewModel" />

  </data>

  <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="10dp">

  </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

I include the layouts programatically into `LinearLayout` with id `layout`, and each viewModel extends BaseViewModel.

Comment: is your `BaseViewModel` an abstract class?

Comment: @StavroXhardha yes, it's an abstract class.

Answer (score 0):

This is how we set ViewModel in dynamic Views.

```
  LayoutInflater lInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
      ItemListBinding itemBinding = ItemListBinding .inflate(lInflater, parent, false);
  itemBinding .setviewModel(viewModel);
  itemBinding.executePendingBindings();
```

Check this blog [here](https://medium.com/@ali.muzaffar/android-recyclerview-using-mvvm-and-databinding-d9c659236908)

Comment: Where should this be? what is ItemListBinding?

Comment: This should be your xml layout name+ Binding . You need to write this in onBindViewHolder. Also you will need to send ViewModel instance to adapter. This code is written in Java . Please convert in Kotlin as it seems you are using that.

Comment: see my edited question. I tried with RecycleviewRowBinding and send added private val viewModels: List<BaseDeviceViewModel> as a new parameter for adapter where I send the instances of viewModel for each view. On onBindViewHolder I added:
val layout = layouts[position]
    val view = mInflater.inflate(layout, null)
    holder.layout.addView(view)
    binding.viewModel = viewModels[position]
    binding.executePendingBindings()
but it is not working. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: how can you have multiple viewmodels ? viewmodel is created per activity/fragment

Comment: You dont need to send ViewModel everywhere you can send the LiveData (List of DataSet) to adapter and in xml use that LiveData instead of ViewModel. Observe the liveData change in Activity/Fragment and notify the adapter in case of change.

Comment: I need to have many cards on recycleView and each card has it's own viewModel.

Comment: I have added a blog link in the answer. Check. That should help you understand how it works.